# what is the best way to store large data in react.js, cookies, localstorage, or any other?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, data-storage

I found some similar questions but this is unique because of the data size itself...

I have an axios request for a large amount of data that gets called only upon starting the app. It is an array of hundreds of thousands of objects. It can take about 1 minute to load the first time through so I would like to store this somewhere so when you open the app, you don't have to wait a minute again. What is the best procedure for this? I was thinking localStorage but I wasn't sure if I could for large amounts of data, or if this was even the best option. I read that 5MB is the max size to store in localstorage so I should ask for both scenarios. Assuming the data size is less than 5MB, is this the best way? And what if it is over 5MB?

Answer (score 2):

The maximum size of session/local storage depends on setting of browser. I don't recommend to use local/session storage for storing large content of data. And Cookie used to be set by set-cookie in response header and also can be set in your client side code manually, but it is not a good way to use it for storing some data.

How about to use indexedDB. The following link can be help for you.

https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2016/08/30/storing-data-client-javascript-typescript.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I will check this out tomorrow and get back to you.